# using readr want to use col_only() option

Tags: r

My question how to use read_csv to read only certain columns BY NAME.  Example:

```
tmp <- read_csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")

dim(tmp)
[1] 4706   46

names(tmp)[c(11,17,23)]
[1] "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Attack" 
[2] "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Failure"
[3] "Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Pneumonia"
```

If I want to use read_csv and use col_only() option how can I only read one of these columns at a time.

Only thing I could come up with was:

```
tt <- read_csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", col_types = cols_only(Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Attack=col_character()), n_max = 10)
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "tt <- read_csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", col_types = cols_only(Hospital 30
```

***I have a solid hunch my problem lays with using the name of the column given by names() , need some guidance.***

Trying to follow this example in my book:

```
logdates <- read_csv("data/2016-07-20.csv.gz", col_types = cols_only(date = col_date()), n_max = 10)
```

Comment: Try using backticks or quotes in your `col_only` argument

Comment: Have you read the help for `read_csv`? do you know what is the `col_types` option. Considere read documention before asking question.

Comment: Thanks I had tried quotes, but backticks did the trick.

Comment: timat -Sorry I am newbie, still getting use to documentation. I was running out of patience is why i turned to stackoverflow, I did try to read doc, and Hadley's page, etc on my own.  Just needed to know if I am way off in my reading my example.  Basically I could tell the name I am using should be input differently.  Cheers

Comment: @timat I have to say, `col_only` help file is not straightforward at all, especially for a newbie

Answer (score 1):

Basically I could tell the name I am using should be input differently.  Per sebastian-c advice backticks did the trick.